# AutoMapper without LINQ

Tags: .net, automapper

How can I map two types and their properties without using LINQ expressions? I have both the source and the target Type and the names of the source and target properties.

Comment: Try to explain what you mean.

Comment: Maybe add an example in your question

Comment: I’m sorry, but this is very obvious and doesn’t need any additional explanation...

Comment: What's wrong with expressions?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but I am building this map dynamically, with Types not known at development time.

Comment: @RicardoPeres you can build expression trees (I assume that what you've meant when wrote "LINQ expressions") dynamically in runtime.

Comment: @RicardoPeres also as you can see the question is not obvious and needs additional explanation.

Comment: If you have a type object, you can create a map for it, that's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple:

```
var sourceType = typeof(SourceType);
var targetType = typeof(TargetType);

var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
{
    var map = x.CreateMap(sourceType, targetType);

    map.ForMember("TargetProperty", dest =>
    {
        dest.MapFrom("SourceProperty");
    });
});

var mapper = new Mapper(cfg);

var a = new SourceType { SourceProperty = "Test" };
var b = new TargetType();

mapper.Map(a, b);
```

Comment: Much Ado About Nothing

Comment: You were one of the ones who created the fuss over a simple, straightforward and objective question

Comment: Yeah, right :) Hopefully someone will put this question out of its misery.

Comment: I just did, nothing more to say or add.

Comment: No, for the future generations :)

Answer (score -1):

Obvious approach

```
public static TargetType ToTarget(this SourceType source)
{
    return new TargetType
    {
        TargetProperty1 = source.SourceProperty1,
        TargetProperty2 = source.SourceProperty2,
        TargetProperty3 = source.SourceProperty3
    };
}

// Usage

var target = source.ToTarget();
```

No LINQ expressions involved ;)

Comment: A very silly example that does not relate at all to my question.

Comment: @RicardoPeres, you should mention in the question that types aren't known at development time and that you are building "map" dynamically to respect others time and saves all from guessing. Otherwise your question deserves this answer ;)

Comment: Really? I thought that was what Type and property names meant...